# NuGet + Package Manager Console

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, package-managers, nuget-package

How do you get documentation on the packages that you install/uninstall?  Every site I find that has any information regarding NuGet or the Package Manager Console is SUPER EXCITED to show you how to install/uninstall a package.

This seems trivial but you would think there'd be some console command that said something like Describe-Package or something or maybe the author could leave a link in the description on the NuGet website but no.  Nothing, nada, zip.

Can someone please put me out of my misery and either tell me there's no official documentation structure for the packages or is there a command where I can view the available commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you the list of available commands in NuGet:

```
Get-Command -Module nuget.visualstudio
```

This is a Powershell command returning a list of type [`CommandInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.commandinfo%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You can then get help about a specific command by doing:

```
Get-Help Install-Package
```

For a summary of all commands, try:

```
Get-Command -Module nuget.visualstudio |% { Get-Help $_.Name | select Name, Synopsis } | Format-Table -Auto
```

You could create an alias for this is you were to use it often.

If you wanted to get the description of a package from a repository:

```
Find-Package -Remote elmah | Select Description
```